# HTML Anchor is not clickable after adding elements to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created an html page that looks like that:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="calendar-cont">
        ...
        <div id="overview">
            <div id="overview-type">
                 <h3>Selected Shift Type</h3>
                 <div id="selected-shift-type-cont"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="overview-dates">
                 <h3>Selected Dates</h3>
                 <ul id="selected-dates-cont"></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="submit-overview">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I also have a jQuery click listener for the  tag:

```
$("#submit-overview").click(function() {
   console.log("click");
   submitDates();
});
```

This listener works as long as the DOM stay the way it is now. Whenever I add an element to the `selected-shift-type-cont` or the `selected-dates-cont` the listener does not work anymore. Does anyone has an idea why this problem occurs?

I add elements this way:

```
var tmp = new Date(date.getTime());
dates[dates.length] = tmp;
$("#selected-dates-cont").append("<li>" + getDateString(tmp, "dd.mm.yyyy") + "</li>");
```

and

```
$("#selected-shift-type-cont").html("<div>" + shiftType.name + "</div>");
```

As soon as one of these two pieces of code are executed, I cannot click the anchor anymore.

**Update:**

I use jQuery 1.9.1. Also I use Chrome (version 28.0.1500.71) for developing. When I test it on Firefox 22 everything works as expected. Since I use the jQuery .load() method to change the main content according to what the user clicked in the navigation bar. Therefore I need to run the website on localhost which I do using the `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001` command on my Mac. This command starts a webserver from the directory I called that command. Is it possible one of these factors might be the problem

**Update 2:**

I did not mention until now that I use the fullCalendar jQuery plugin. I also created a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem http://jsfiddle.net/XagK5/3/. It contains all important parts, I also included the whole fullCalendar minified javascript code, because I did not know how to include an external script.

**Update 3:**

It does work if I add the following CSS:

```
#submit-overview {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Try `$(document).on("click","#submit-overview",function() {` instead of `$("#submit-overview").click(function() {` delegating the event handler.

Comment: But should it not work with .click() also? Why this strange behavior? Are you duplicating the id #submit-overview in the added content? Also: where is your JavaScript placed and when is it run?

Comment: Benjamin Gruenbaum, I've tried that too and that changed nothing...

Comment: I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work. Are you able to reproduce the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: have to tried using .live

Comment: @PhilemonphilipKunjumon `live()` was deprecated in `v1.7` and removed in `1.9`

Comment: @billyonecan :- he has not mentioned which version of jquery he is using..

Comment: @mvieghofer Please mention the version which you are using..?/

Comment: @billyonecan: no the jsFiddle provided by LastCoder works, so I think that my code should work, too

Comment: @Omar: I don't think it is a duplicate of the question you posted since my links aren't added dynamically. Also the link is no in a list.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear and seemed about attaching events to dynamically added elements. Since you've revised your question and added more relevant data, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/72wyN/1/

Everything works for me with FF 22.

You must be using an older (read: obsolete) version of jQuery or your code is doing more than you showed us or your browser is defunct. Please elaborate further.

```
$("#submit-overview").click(function() {
   console.log("click");
   alert("still works");
});
window.setInterval(function() {
    $("#selected-dates-cont").append("<li>1/1/2000</li>");
    $("#selected-shift-type-cont").html("<div>blah</div>");
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Hi, I've added some extra information to the question. Also your jsFiddle works as expected, so the code I wrote should work, too...